# Crawl image and their metadata using nutch and index them into solr

Tags: image, apache, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I want to build a mini image based search engine to which I can provide image file and it will search for similar images in the solr. I'm using nutch for the crawling part and indexing the data into solr. I've done changes into nutch conf files like -

- Added `image/*` into `mimetype-filter.txt`
- Removed image extensions from `suffix-urlfilter.txt` - not to skip them

I also added fields into solr schema.xml -

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="iso" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="iso_string" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="aperture" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="exposure" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="exposure_time" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="focal" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="focal_35" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="string" indexed="false" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

But when I crawl, there is no data that is indexed into solr. I'm unable to find any documentation/tutorial regarding this. I've also gone through some posts on stackoverflow for image crawling using nutch. But I didn't find those helpful.

Can someone please guide me to the right direction regarding how to proceed ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check this blogpost https://lobster1234.github.io/2017/08/14/search-with-nutch-mongodb-solr ? Once you have it running for text, you can adapt it for images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy/short answer for this issue, parsing images is a tricky business, even without involving the crawling part. On top of what you've already done you need first to enable the `parse-tika` plugin (`parse-html` only deals with HTML documents). Apache Tika is able to extract some metadata about the images.

You also need to enable the `mimetype-filter` plugin (this is not only editing the config file but enabling in the `nutch-site.xml` file). After these configurations are done you should try the `bin/nutch parsechecker <URL>` tool to test a URL that contains some images and see if you can find the URLs to the images in the `Outlinks` section. Also, check running the parsechecker against an image URL to see what metadata the parsechecker is extracting. After this, run the `bin/nutch indexchecker` tool against both URLs and check which fields it is going to index into Solr and create those in your schema accordingly. Keep in mind that Tika may extracty different metadata for each format.

Comment: I did the same thing you have mentioned. My requirement is to get results (text as well as images) based on the searched keyword. Text search is working very well. But during the parsing stage of the images(bin/nutch parsechecker <IMG_URL>) the image name is not listed in the meta data. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'm guessing that by name you mean the file name of the image right? Are you using Solr by any chance? If yes then you can extract the filename from the URL that is already present (and sent to Solr). In that case you can copy the URL into a different field (like `filename`) and use `solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory` (on the new field) to extract the filename from the URL.

Comment: it worked..  I copied the same and extracted image name into a new field  using ```solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory```
But I'm afraid that the new field content is not used for searching. I am not getting results of those. Do you have any idea.?

Comment: This really depends more on your Solr configuration and which query parser you are using. For instance, if you are using/can use the DisMax query parser you could use the `qf` parameter (see https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqf_QueryFields_Parameter). Another option is to have an extra field for searching, use `copyField` in your schema to copy from the other fields into this "bag of text" field and define it as the default search field (`df` parameter). You can also modify your query like `content:bla OR filename:bla`.